# HTML bootstrap dl-horizontal not working as expected

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Though i have div class "dl-horizontal" inside the table, the dl-horizontal fields appear to be outside the table
Code which i used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
   <caption>Event <span class="badge">2</span></caption>
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                  <dt>field-1</dt><dd>14</dd>
                  <dt>field-2</dt><dd>13</dd>
                  <dt>field-3</dt><dd>12</dd>
              </dl>
    <tr>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Field5</th>
     <th>Field6</th>
     <th>Field7</th>
     <th>Field8</th>
     <th>Field9</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="text-nowrap">2018-11-13</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>val5</td>
     </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

What am i missing in this? I am trying to get "dl-horizontal" fields inside EVENT and above table values. any help is greatly appreciated. i tried table inside a the table but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: <dl> tag is not a valid <table> tag, the only way to include it in table is to create a separate table row and data row in the table, for example: <table><tr><td  colspan="6"><dl><dt></dt><dd></dd></dl></td></tr></table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This it the correct approach:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
            <caption>Event <span class="badge">2</span></caption>
              <tr><td colspan="6">
              <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                  <dt>field-1</dt><dd>14</dd>
                  <dt>field-2</dt><dd>13</dd>
                  <dt>field-3</dt><dd>12</dd>
              </dl>
              </td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Field5</th>
                    <th>Field6</th>
                    <th>Field7</th>
                    <th>Field8</th>
                    <th>Field9</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-nowrap">2018-11-13</td>
                        <td>val2</td>
                        <td>val2</td>
                        <td>val4</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>val5</td>
                    </tr>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to place your description list with a table element for it to be included as part of the table. This snippet places it within the caption tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <caption>Event <span class="badge">2</span>
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>field-1</dt>
        <dd>14</dd>
        <dt>field-2</dt>
        <dd>13</dd>
        <dt>field-3</dt>
        <dd>12</dd>
      </dl>
    </caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Field5</th>
      <th>Field6</th>
      <th>Field7</th>
      <th>Field8</th>
      <th>Field9</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-nowrap">2018-11-13</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>val5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <caption>Event <span class="badge">2</span>
    </caption>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
          <dt>field-1</dt>
          <dd>14</dd>
          <dt>field-2</dt>
          <dd>13</dd>
          <dt>field-3</dt>
          <dd>12</dd>
        </dl>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Field5</th>
      <th>Field6</th>
      <th>Field7</th>
      <th>Field8</th>
      <th>Field9</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-nowrap">2018-11-13</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>val5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this case, the description-list gets the caption properties(you can see a light gray for the description list). should i add seperate style properties for description list ?

Comment: You will need to give it it's own styling. I've changed the snippet to show a seconds table where the list is placed with tr and td tags if you prefer that styling instead. But I'm guessing you'd want it something different.